# How to convert an XML to junit XML?

Tags: xml, jenkins, junit

A python script is run in jenkins and saves the test results as html and xml files. 
How do I convert this xml file to **JUNIT understandable XML file**? 
[Example XML File on github](https://github.com/TheGoldenHorn/Example-XML/blob/master/finalResult_172.217.163.100_443.xml)

*This is the funnction I am using to convert the pandas dataframe to XML:*

```
def to_xml(df, filename=None, mode='w'):
    def row_to_xml(row):
        xml = ['<testsuite>']
        for i, col_name in enumerate(row.index):
            xml.append('  <testcase class="{0}">{1}</testcase>'.format(col_name, row.iloc[i]))
        xml.append('</testsuite>')
        return '\n'.join(xml)
    res = '\n'.join(df.apply(row_to_xml, axis=1))

    if filename is None:
        return (f"<testsuites>\n{res.replace('<=','&gt;')}\n</testsuites>")
    with open(filename, mode) as f:
        f.write((f"<testsuites>\n{res.replace('<=','&gt;')}\n</testsuites>"))
```

Comment: It depends of the format of your xml file and on what your python script does. Can you provide the xml file you want to convert and the python script that creates this file ?

Comment: @SmartTom The python file is more of a framework that I have written to test for vulnerabilities. I am converting the pandas dataframe to an xml. I can provide the xml file.

Comment: @SmartTom added the xml to github and python function here.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your python script that creates your XML file to comply to the JUnit XML format.

You can find documentation about this format [here](https://llg.cubic.org/docs/junit/).

Comment: sure I am on it. Thanks for all the help.